# MVC3 - jQuery unobtrusive validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC and need some guidance for the problem that I am running into.

I have a text field to contain Date using date picker. In the model, I didn't specify to validate the text field.

But I submit the form, the jQuery unobstrusive validates the date text field.

#### The model

```
Using System;
Using System. Collections. Generic;
Using System. ComponentModel;
Using System. ComponentModel. DataAnnotations;
Using System. Linq;
Using System. Web;
Using DataAnnotationsExtensions;


Namespace heavy_haulage_general_freight. Models
{

    public class nsc_gf_job
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime pickup_date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### The View

```
@model heavy_haulage_general_freight. Models. Nsc_gf_job    
@using heavy_haulage_general_freight. Helpers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html. BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Resources Division Heavy Haulage Details:</legend>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Label("Pickup Date")</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox("pickup_date", "") <br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("pickup_date")
                    </td>                
                <tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a nullable date  - ie

```
 public DateTime? pickup_date { get; set; }
```

also note this applies to ints as well, as there is no 'empty' default for an int, you need a nullable value

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you have defined the property of type `DateTime` in your model. Validation will always happen for this type because you cannot assign an invalid value to such field.